# Java remote debugging with Maven and Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, debugging, netbeans, remote-debugging

I'm trying to remotely debug a jar file bundled with dependencies created with maven-assembly-plugin. But everything I do, and no matter how I call the debugger on the machine running the code (or on my local machine for testing) I always get a "Could not find main class". That's the message even if I specify the exact main class in the command line.

POM file:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.xxx.yyy.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm creating the jar with dependencies with:

```
clean compiler:compile assembly:single
```

The debugging is started with:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8800,server=y,suspend=y -classpath %classpath com.xxx.yyy.MyMainClass pubsubtest-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The application starts and says:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8800
```

But when I connect to the port with Netbeans the issue is:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.xxx.yyy.MyMainClass
```

Am I missing something? Should I setup Netbeans somehow? In Netbeans I'm keeping the project open.

I followed this tutorial:
https://blogs.oracle.com/atishay/entry/use_netbeans_to_debug_a

Comment: First of all, forget debugging. Can you *run* the app normally from the command line? Also, your command-line invocation looks weird - you shouldn't need the JAR as the last argument (although the JAR needs to be on the classpath). Also, if you have a main-class defined, you shouldn't need to even specify a class name.

Comment: Yes I can run it basically without any errors, but I need to change it further and the issue is I can only test it on the remote virtual machine because it can only work on it due to some other components only available in the LAN of that virtual machine, its a project policy issue, I'm just a guest.
So how should the invocation look then?\